# Unity - Stop When Building

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

I have finished my game in Unity already.
But whenever I'm trying to build the game, it stops at the point as shown below. Does anyone know the reason why it happens? It always stops at the same point....

[image]

Comment: Try unchecking the three checkboxes.. Development Build, Autoconnect Profiler, Script Debugging and build project.

Comment: @NeverHopeless Yeah.. I did that.. but still the same thing

Comment: Is this for just the selected platform or for any other too. trying building on that ? Same issue ? Are you building first time and getting error or it was building in the past and having issues now ? What is the game size ? May be it takes some time more than expected ? Try excluding stuff from your game and build then.

Comment: Also, in tracking down build errors, open up the Editor Log (from console window menu, or run Console (from Spotlight) and choose ~/Library/Logs/Unity/Editor.log). Clear that first, then build. It will show you what it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with baking the lightmaps on your scene.

Unity doesn't like huge objects when it comes to baking lightmaps on them and it can certainly kill the light transport on a build.

You can try to open the Window menu from the main Unity menubar and search for the **"Continues baking"** checkbox under Lightning and uncheck it.

Or you can just split your bigger objects on your scene which may cause this problem.

Here's a [thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/light-transport-problem-with-large-objects.310405/) detailing the issue a bit.

I've also [seen people working around this problem by disabling Global Illumination](http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/stuck-at-clustering-jobs-when-baking-lightmaps) altogether so that may be a solution for you as well if you are using it and you are willing to give up on that feature.

Edit: [Another thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-bake-lightmaps-on-huge-objects-in-the-scene.307961/) about this sort of thing with a decent solution - not sure why I didn't remember it for first but it's a good idea before trying to split your huge objects to mess with their "**Scale In Lightmap**" property as well to reduce the lightmaps' size.

You can also try the **"Advanced Parameter"** options.

Comment: I deleted things not needed.. but this time it stops even before that.. and it's clustering problem.. does it mean like I delete something I should not delete?

Comment: Probably - can you recall what objects have you deleted from your scene? Also the issue ticket I was linking in my answer was starting from a clustering problem as well but he could solve that by setting the color space to linear in player settings. You should give that a try and see if it works for you.